# SwiftUI add a -y offset to a view but stretching the view to bottom

Tags: swiftui

I have 2 views in my code, a VStack and then a custom view.

I am adding an offset to the second view of -75, to move it on top of the first view.

Here is my current code:

```
Group {
       VStack {
           //First View
           VStack {
               Image("LogoCrest")

                NavigationLink(destination: LocationSearch()) {
                    Text("Find a location")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .bold()
                    .padding()
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: Alignment.center)
                .background(Color(red: 81 / 255, green: 175 / 255, blue: 67 / 255))
                .cornerRadius(7)
                .padding()

           }
           .padding(.top, 75)
           .padding(.bottom, 75)
           .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: Alignment.center)
           .background(Color(red: 49 / 255, green: 49 / 255, blue: 49 / 255))

           //Second view
           CircuitList(Circuits: Circuits)
            .offset(y: -75)
           .padding()
       }
     }
    .background(Color(red: 232 / 255, green: 232 / 255, blue: 232 / 255))
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```

How can I increase the height of the second view so it can always be at the bottom (see the black line in the image below for my desired extra height)?

[image: My view]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have found the answer.
Since I added `y:-75` offset to my view, I had to add `y:-75` padding too.

```
CircuitList(Circuits: Circuits)
    .offset(y: -75)
    .padding()
    .padding(.bottom, -75)
```

Comment: Yeah, When we use the offset() modifier, we’re changing the location where a view should be rendered without actually changing its underlying geometry. Thats why we have to add minus padding to.

Comment: Perfect answer I was looking for

Comment: Amazing answer I was using `position` and adding the negative padding back to account for that offset fixed my empty space issue.